# WooCommerce Custom Field in Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I want add Custom field in WooCommerce checkout page but for selected products.

For e.g if Client have **Product A** in cart only than this custom field should appear in **WooCommerce Checkout Page**

I am using following code in functions.php to add custom field:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_delivery_checkout_field');

function my_delivery_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

echo '<div id="my_local_club"><h3>'.__('Delivery Options').'</h3>';

woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_options', array(
'type' => 'select',
'class' => array('my-club-class form-row-wide'),
'label' => _('<br><br>Please select your options', 'woocommerce'),
'required' => true,
'placeholder' => _x('Please Select An Option...', 'placeholder','woocommerce'),
'options' => array(
'option1' => 'Option 1',
'option_2' =>'Option 2',
 'option_3' =>'Option 3'
)
), $checkout->get_value( 'delivery_options' ));

echo '</div>';

}
```

Comment: Delivery options should likely be handled using the (very robust) shipping system.

Comment: Hi cale_b actually it is not for delivery options, client wants to add additional user input field in checkout page just to get notified that's it

Answer (score 2):

So following code solve my problem thanks to StackOverFlow.com

```
/**
* Add the field to the checkout
**/
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_delivery_checkout_field');

function my_delivery_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    //Check if gift card is in cart
    $book_in_cart = conditional_product_in_cart( 7267 );

if ( $book_in_cart === true ) {
echo '<div id="my_local_club"><h3>'.__('Delivery Options').'</h3>';

woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_options', array(
'type' => 'select',
'class' => array('my-club-class form-row-wide'),
'label' => _('<br><br>Please select your options', 'woocommerce'),
'required' => true,
'placeholder' => _x('Please Select An Option...', 'placeholder','woocommerce'),
'options' => array(
'option1' => 'Option 1',
'option_2' =>'Option 2',
 'option_3' =>'Option 3'
)
), $checkout->get_value( 'delivery_options' ));

echo '</div>';
}
}




// Check if Gift card is in the cart

function conditional_product_in_cart( $product_id ) {
 //Check to see if user has product in cart
 global $woocommerce;

 //flag no book in cart
 $book_in_cart = false;

 foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
 $_product = $values['data'];

 if ( $_product->id === $product_id ) {
 //book is in cart!
 $book_in_cart = true;

 }
 }

 return $book_in_cart;

}
```